# What is the proper way in JavaScript to make an object's member function invoke when the object is created?

Tags: javascript, oop

So the situation I have is like

```
function MyObject ( data ) 
{
     // ... 
     this.MyMemberFunction = function ( ) { /* ... */ };
}
```

and I want `MyMemberFunction` to be invoked when a new `MyObject` is created. So I want the equivalent of

```
var myObjectInstance = new MyObject(allData);
myObjectInstance.MyMemberFunction();
```

or

```
function MyObject ( data ) 
{
     // ... 
     this.MyMemberFunction = function ( ) { /* ... */ };
     this.MyMemberFunction();
}
var myObjectInstance = new MyObject(allData);
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better, i.e. more proper, way than either of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object's constructor is where you should initialize an object to be in proper working order and it's where you should put any code that should be called for all new creations of an object.  It is very common for an object to have a `.init()` method that is called from the constructor that performs common setup code for the object.

So, calling your method in the constructor is the right thing to do if it contains code that should always be called on all new objects.

You do have another option for where you define your method.  It may make sense to put it on the prototype rather than assign it in the constructor.

```
function MyObject ( data ) {
     // ... 
     this.myMemberFunction();
}

MyObject.prototype.myMemberFunction = function ( ) { /* ... */ };


var myObjectInstance = new MyObject(allData);
```

Note: A common convention in Javascript is for constructor functions to start with an uppercase letter, but for regular functions or members to start with a lowercase letter.  Since constructor functions should be called differently (using `new`), this identifies them differently.

Note: If your initialization method does not need to be a public method that can be called from the outside world, then it does not have to be an actual public method on the object.  You can put the code inline in the constructor or in a private function that is only available within the scope of your object's file.

Comment: I'm confused about my `myFunctionFunction` is coming from in your code sample

Comment: myFunctionFunction is in the original question.

Comment: @SubparWebDev - That was copied from the OP's question, not sure why it did not match the declaration and invocation in the question (probably just a typo).  I've edited my answer to `myMemberFunction()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't know I made a type-o. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another alternative using `prototype`:

```
var Person = function ( data ) 
{
  // ... 
  this.doSomething();
}

Person.prototype.doSomething = function ( ) { /* ... */ };

var myObjectInstance = new Person(allData);
```

But, I could not say it is "the better" since it definitely depends on what are you developing